# Free LaTeX editor for Mac with outline view?

Tags: editors, mac

I'm looking for a **LaTeX editor** for **Mac OS X** that supports **larger projects**, so should have some form of **outline view** showing the logical structure of a larger project that extends across many files.

Is this possible with TeXShop?

If not can you recommend another editor, that is free?

Comment: TextMate shows the structure of a document.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [TeXStudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) or [TexMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/).